# AWS - Java Lambda - move data from s3 to redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Does any one have working example to copy s3 file into redshift. can you please share any example in java or any url to refer

Comment: FYI, you will need to use a JDBC library to connect to Amazon Redshift (it behaves like PostgreSQL). Once connected, you can issue the [COPY command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html).

Comment: BTW, a popular choice is to do this with a Lambda function written in Python, since it can use the [psycopg2 library](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/).

Comment: is it possible to call COPY command from lambda function

Comment: It is not possible to _directly_ call the `COPY` command. Amazon Redshift only accepts connections via JDBC or ODBC. You will need an SQL Client library to connect and run the `COPY` command. This is the same way that applications connect to traditional databases.

Comment: Please use Redshift Data API. And python boto3 has SDK for Data API.